# Django signals dispatch_uid

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a question regarding the usage of `dispatch_uid` for signals.

Currently, I am preventing multiple usage of the signal by simply adding `if not instance.order_reference`. I wonder now if `dispatch_uid` has the same functionality and I can delete the *"`if not`"* clause.

**signals.py**

```py
def reserveditem_create_order_reference(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_reference:
        instance.order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
```

**app.py**

```py
class OrdersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'orders'

    def ready(self):

        #Pre save signal for ReservedItem model
        reserved_model = self.get_model('ReservedItem')
        pre_save.connect(
            reserveditem_create_order_reference,
            sender=reserved_model,
            dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier"
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As by [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals),

> In some circumstances, the code connecting receivers to signals may run multiple times. This can cause your receiver function to be registered more than once, and thus called multiple times for a single signal event. If this behavior is problematic (such as when using signals to send an email whenever a model is saved), pass a unique identifier as the dispatch_uid argument to identify your receiver function

So yes, removing the `if` clause and setting a unique signal receiver `dispatch_uid` instead will prevent your handlers from being connected (and thereafter, called) more than once.